# React UseState initial reference gets altered when edited in function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with a reference that for some reason is being edited all the way through the call-stack.

1. First I import a JSON array with a series of objects called `groups.json`
2. On first load I add groups to `setFetchedGroups`
3. Then I call `removeChildren` with my `fetchedGroups` as argument
4. The `removeChildren` function removes a child object

   ```
   import groups from '../../../data/groups.json'    

   const [fetchedGroups, setFetchedGroups] = useState([])

   //Set initial state
   useEffect(() => {
       setFetchedGroups(groups)
   }, [])

   removeChildren(fetchedGroups[0])

   const removeChildren= (sourceArray) => {
       sourceArray[0].children.splice(1, 1)
   }
   ```

For some reason, everything is getting edited. When I print respectively `fetchedGroups` and `groups`, the child object that I removed gets removed from everyting.

I cannot understand why this happens, I was under the impression that `fetchedGroups` could only be edited through the use of `setFetchedGroups`

Therefore:

- Why does this happen?
- How can I avoid altering the reference?

Comment: It looks like `groups` is a 2D array. You are setting `fetchedGroups` to a *reference* to that array. That array is actually an array of references to other arrays. So `groups[0]` is actually a reference to an array. Editing that array will cause all references to it to see the changes. To avoid this, either restructure the code or make a copy. You can look into  [RFDC](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rfdc) if you want to make deep copies of nested arrays.

Comment: You shouldn't be mutating state directly in the first place. Your `removeChildren` handler should be calling `setFetchedGroups(prev => ...)` and handling the removal in a clone inside the callback passed. `useState` provides no guarantees of immutability.

Comment: You might also look into [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) as well to see if that suits your needs. For example, you could make a copy in the reducer function.

Comment: If you change the contents of a state directly (without setState), the changes will not propagate right away but they will propagate whenever your screen re-renders due to another state change. If you don't want that to happen, you should never change the state directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an example, if you have

```
groups = [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ];
fetchedGroups = groups;
```

`groups` is actually an array of 3 references. `fetchedGroups` is a reference to that array.

It looks like this:

```
fetchedGroups----+
                 |
                 V
groups---------->[  o  ,  o  ,  o  ];
                    |     |     |
                    |     |     |
          [1,2,3]<--+     |     +-->[7,8,9]
                          V
                       [4,5,6]
```

so `fetchedGroups[0]` and `groups[0]` are pointing to the same underlying data.
If you directly set `fetchedGroups[0] = [0,0,0]`, then you end up with this:

```
fetchedGroups----+
                 |
                 V
groups---------->[  o  ,  o  ,  o  ];
                    |     |     |
                    |     |     |
          [0,0,0]<--+     |     +-->[7,8,9]
                          V
                       [4,5,6]
```

Now `groups[0]` is also `[0,0,0]` as well.

When you call `removeChildren(fetchedGroups[0])`, that modifies the underlying data directly. So that's why you see those changes when you look at the `groups` variable as well. State can be mutated directly, and it's not advised.

To avoid this, you can make copies of the data for your state. [RFDC](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rfdc) can help you if your object is deeply nested. Also, deeply nested React state tends to be discouraged where possible, but that doesn't mean you can't use it.